# Design Patterns for System Functions?

Tags: coding-style, downvalues, code-organization, code

Using `PrintDefinitions` give one a great view into many system functions. Often the design of these symbols incorporate multiple patterns that I see again and again. To name a few:

- For a symbol XYZ, there is iXYZ[], aXYZ[], etc...
- Use of so called “router” subroutines.
- Specialized failure catch/throw mechanisms
- Fancy nonstandard option handlings
- Autoloading/Dumping contexts

The source doesn’t look at all like the normal functions people write in packages. So I was hoping a developer could respond with a little tutorial on any interesting patterns that WRI likes to use for some built-in functions.

Comment: I've never seen an `aXYZ` -- what's an example? I think of `iXYZ` as "internal XYZ."  The parent `XYZ[]` does argument checking and possibly other preprocessing of arguments and options; then sends the prepared arguments to `iXYZ[]` for the main computation. If the main computation fails, the internal function often returns `$Failed`, which causes `XYZ[]` to return unevaluated. Something like this: `XYZ[args___] := Module[{res}, (* check/process args *); res = iXYZ[args]; res /; FreeQ[res, $Failed]];` As noted, they sometimes use `Catch` and `Throw` for a nonlocal return of `$Failed`.

Comment: "Fancy nonstandard option handlings" explains why do many builtins have broken option handling ... in particular, why many won't pick up things set with `SetOptions`.

Comment: I really don't think there many techniques used there which are not in some answers scattered on this site. What you mentioned amounts to using `SubValues`,  local variables shared between the `Module / With` and the condition, exceptions with custom tags to fail early, delegeation of implementation to dedicated separate internal functions. All of that has been discussed in some Q/As on this site.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin That maybe true but the keyword is scattered. A unified answer combining these and more internal folklore would be quite helpful!

Comment: I will try to remember to return to this Q/A when I get a spare moment big enough to do it justice. Not sure when that will be though. Hopefully someone else would jump in in the mean time.